# A question on geodesics on a cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry

I have solved an exercise on gedeosics on a cylinder but I have a question that makes me doubt the correctness.

[image]

My strategy to solve this was as follows:

1. Determine and solve the geodesic equations.
2. Show that the solutions are parametrizations of helices, circles and straight lines.
3. Investigate how many solutions one can have when they are required to run through specific points.

Consider the system of standard coordinate frames $\{\partial_i\}_{i=1,2}$ where $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. In order to find the geodesic equations we need the Christoffel symbols. We have

$$
\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j
=\sum_{k=1}^2 \Gamma^k_{ij} \partial_k 
$$

Then we apply the metric and exploit the orthogonality of the frames to get

$$
\langle \nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j , \partial_k \rangle 
=\langle \sum_{l=1}^3 \Gamma^l_{ij} \partial_l, \partial_k \rangle 
=\sum_{l=1}^2 \Gamma^l_{ij} 
\langle \partial_l, \partial_k \rangle
=\Gamma^k_{ij} 
$$

The Koszul formula yields the Christoffel identity

$$
\langle \nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j , \partial_k \rangle
=\frac{1}{2} 
(\partial_i \langle \partial_j, \partial_k \rangle 
+\partial_j \langle \partial_k, \partial_i \rangle
-\partial_k \langle \partial_i, \partial_j \rangle) 
$$

Since the frames are orthogonal we get

$$
\langle \nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j , \partial_k \rangle=0
$$

But then all of the Christoffel symbols vanish. The geodesic equations take the form

$$
0=\gamma^{''}_k+\sum_{i,j=1}^3 \gamma'_i \gamma'_j (\Gamma^k_{ij} \circ \gamma)
=\gamma^{''}_k, \ k=1,2 \ ,  \gamma=(\gamma_1\gamma_2). 
$$

Thus we have the solutions

$$
\gamma_k(t)=a_k+b_k t
$$

The cylinder can be parametrized as

$$
C(x_1,x_2)=(\cos(x_1),\sin(x_1),x_2), x_2 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

so the geodesics arise as

$$
C(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))=(\cos(\gamma_1(t)),\sin(\gamma_1(t)),\gamma_2(t))
$$

This is

- a helix if $b_1,b_2 \neq 0$
- a circle if $b_1 \neq 0$ and $b_2=0$
- a straight line if $b_1=0$ and $b_2 \neq 0$.

Now consider $p,q \in M$.

If the solution is a helix we have infinitely many possible choices for $b_2$ and therefore infinitely many geodesics connecting $p$ and $q$.

If the solution is a circle we have two choices for the sign of $b_1$ and therefore two geodesics connecting $p$ and $q$.

If the solution is a straight line we have infinitely many possible choices for $b_2$ and therefore infinitely many geodesics connecting $p$ and $q$.

However, this solution does not take into account the $a_k$ which raises a question: Since there are no conditions imposed on these parameters shouldn't there be always infinitely many geodesics?

Comment: In fact there are always infinitely many geodesics between two points on a cylinder. And on a cone as well.

Comment: What do you mean by a straight line on the cylinder? Think about this geometrically. Changing $b_2$ does not change the curve, does it? And for a circle, are there only two options?